# Ruby Geocoder near working unexpectedly

Tags: google-maps, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0, rails-geocoder

Using Alex Reisner's [Ruby Geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder), I have a model "Spot" which is geocoded using this gem

If I select the first spot into and object:

```
s = Spot.first
```

Then try to find all the spots within a 10 mile radius (let's say there should be 12 of them), then i would expect **Spot.near(s,10)** to return an active record object containing 12 spots. Instead it's just returning something like this every time:

```
Spot.near(s1,10)
 => {:select=>"spots.*,  AS distance, CAST(DEGREES(ATAN2( RADIANS(spots.longitude - -6.88671972656243), RADIANS(spots.latitude - 55.1729431175342))) + 360 AS decimal) % 360 AS bearing", :conditions=>["spots.latitude BETWEEN 55.028211334423354 AND 55.31767490064505 AND spots.longitude BETWEEN -7.140145500612388 AND -6.633293952512472 AND  <= ?", 10], :order=>"distance ASC"}
```

Basically it's returning some SQL but no results.

What's going wrong here? Even if i try something a lot wider, like:

```
Spot.near([40,0],10000)
```

I still basically get no results back...

**EDIT**

I am able to execute the query using this (not pretty) addition...

```
q = Spot.near(s1,10)
spots = Spot.select(q[:select]).where(q[:conditions]).order(q[:order])
```